# Calculating decimal representation of an integer in Java

Tags: java, integer, decimal

This might seem really naive but I am not sure what is the decimal representation of an integer?

Can you provide some code in Java to convert an integer to its decimal representation?

Thanks!

Comment: I was asked this question in an interview and I just didn't know what it meant.

Comment: @AngryPanda Well you should've asked them, not us.

Comment: @Kayaman - I did and the recruiter said just list out your assumptions. I'd appreciate if you could help me out on this as I am equally lost.

Comment: That's a weird question to ask on an interview. The decimal representation of an integer is just the way we're used to represent integers. Let `x` be the number ten. Its decimal representation would be 10, its binary representation would be 0b1010, its hexa representation would be 0xA, and so on. I don't get it.

Comment: I'd say "I assume you're wasting my time. Good day sir." and leave. But "calculating the decimal representation of an integer" is pretty much nonsense.

Comment: Well I think for example, the decimal representation of number 6 is 6.0?

Comment: @HusseinElFeky Nope. The decimal (base 10) representation of 6 is 6, and it doesn't involve any calculations.

Comment: @Kayaman Ok, thanks. That question on the interview really makes no sense. It's so weird.

Comment: @Kayaman We could say there is a little calculation involved: 6 is 6*1 like 523 would be 5*100 + 2*10 + 3*1. Maybe the interviewer wanted this composition. Or maybe not.

Comment: @AngryPanda What job did you apply for? I am always curious these interviews have full of weird (and sometimes nonsensical) questions.

Comment: The problem with some recruiters is that they do not know the meaning of the question either...

Comment: I applied for a Software Developer's role

Answer (score 2):

My answer would have been [`Integer.toString(value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29).

Done! I have now "calculated" the decimal representation of an integer (`int` value).
As the javadoc says:

> The argument is converted to signed **decimal representation** and returned as a string.

Of course, they probably wanted you to write the code that *implements* that method, rather than using the library method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use things like this :

```
 Integer i = 10;
 Double iDecimal = new Double(i);
 System.out.println(iDecimal); //would print 10.0 i.e. decimal
```